# How to recover -z axis of camera from Rotation Translation Matrix

Tags: camera, transforms, motion-capture

Say I have a Rotation Translation Matrix `RT` which describes the rigid body motion of the camera.

[image: RT]

The camera frame is defined as:

- **-z** is the pointing axis
- **y** is "up"
- **x** just othogonal to **y, z**

---

How can I recover **z** from the `RT` matrix?

Comment: Could you elaborate on R and t ?

Comment: Just multiply a Z vector [0,0,1] by that rotation matrix? What is the problem?

Comment: I forgot, to get the rotation matrix decompose your RT matrix: `loc, rot, scale = RT.decompose()`.